# Android Project No Errors, but red X---Noting Core Library Dependency Issue

Tags: android, eclipse

I am newer to Android and after forking an app and resolving dependencies and imports, running the project simply noted "there are errors in the project" and below appeared. No red x's appeared on anything else aside from the AppTitle in the left pane of eclipse...

> ```
> [2014-01-10 23:54:57 - MainActivity] Dx trouble processing "javax/crypto/SealedObject.class":
> ```
>
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
>   when not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
>   in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
>   Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
>   core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
>   going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
>   namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
>   from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
>   assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
>   compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
>   It is also often of questionable legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
>   distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
>   the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
>   building an application, then be forewarned that your application
>   will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
>   prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
>   application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
>   system. You will be to blame for this problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
>   core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
>   repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
>   your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
>   conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
>   you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
>   that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
>   lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
>
> ```
> [2014-01-10 23:54:57 - MainActivity] Dx 1 error; aborting
> [2014-01-10 23:54:57 - MainActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
> ```

Comment: Be sure that your library project must be in same drive like C: or D: as your workspace is in.

Comment: Everything is on the C: drive

Comment: check whether you `android x.x` is included in `buildpath`

Comment: it is included in the build path. I have all my JARS checked, including: Android 4.3, Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies

Comment: Seems like you have `javax.crypto.SealedObject` in your code while you shouldn't. The `javax.` package prefix is special. It can also be because you're incorrectly including the platform jars in your code.

Comment: Solved the problem, had an android.jar in the build path, also had many duplicate .jars of the same name but varying age. It runs but does not connect/send messages to the server. I'll start a new thread for that tommorrow